# Detecting `.configure` dependencies in Debian

Tags: debian, configure, deb

To package applications as Debian packages for personal use, I need to know what are their dependencies.

The `auto-apt` command installs the dependencies of a `./configure` script automatically.  `aut-apt` has an option to run a simulation, and my understanding is that such simulation will let you know what packages would be installed.  However, as far as I can see, `auto-apt` will not tell you what dependencies are already installed (because you installed them before for some other software).

Comment: The usual way to do this is to start in a clean/minimal chroot. Alternatively, when you have constructed a list of dependencies, check it in a clean/minimal chroot.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: How could I start with a clean chroot? By using `debootstrap`?

Comment: Sure, for example. There are tools like schroot, sbuild, pbuilder etc. that help with this.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Please convert your comment to an answer, so that I can choose it.

Comment: Indeed, the recommended tools to do this are pbuilder/cowbuilder.

Comment: @Elena Done. Did you want me to expand on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to start in a clean/minimal chroot. Alternatively, when you have constructed a list of dependencies, check the correctness of the list in a clean/minimal chroot. There are tools like schroot, sbuild, pbuilder, cowbuilder etc. that can help in creating and managing such a chroot.